# How can i read streaming/video from this intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, video-streaming

I have read on the internet from other discussions on stackoverflow that this is the best way to view a streaming stream without immowing dependencies external to the application:

```
//videoURL = 'url:3030/stream'
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(videoURL));
startActivity(intent);
```

Unlike other intentions that link to a class that shows their content, however, this intent shows nothing.
How can I view the contents of this intent?

Comment: Please describe more and Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21620550/how-to-play-a-streaming-video-from-url-in-android

Comment: @D-johnAnshani I had already read it, but it can not be the solution, because it plays only videos with a defined length, that is, with a beginning and an end, while I want to read from a streaming.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a `video view` and set the Uri to the uri of the stream using the `VideoView.setUri(uri)` method.

This tutorial talks about this:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/streaming-video-in-android-apps--cms-19888

However if you want to stream a live video or some other format not supported by VideoView you can use the `vlc-sdk`.

Read into this:
http://www.truiton.com/2015/03/stream-rtmp-live-android/